# Xcode 5.1 unused consts treated as error

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode

Since upgrading to Xcode 5.1 this morning, a C++ library I have included in my project is failing to build due to unused const.

I have Treat Warnings as Errors: NO & Pedantic Warnings: NO

Any ideas?

**Edit after request for line!**:

```
const int NPT_SSDP_MAX_LINE_SIZE  = 2048;
```

full warning is:
Shell script Invocation Error
Unused variable 'NPT_SSDP_MAX_LINE_SIZE'

Comment: Could you show that line?

Comment: added line. Comment this out, and there are others.  This is a 3rd party lib, rather not edit it unless necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have any warning about "Validate Project Settings" in your project?. Similar error went away after update to recommended settings and compile again.

Comment: Don't get why, but yes this worked! Have linker issues now..but 1 step further, thanks!

Comment: Actually, in addition to this - I needed to set treat warnings as errors to NO on the top level project, not just the relevant target(s)

Comment: Where does the validate project settings button appears? Seems that I keep seeing it occasionally, but not now

Comment: @AlexStone It's not a button, it's a warning you can see in the navigator panel. See [image](http://i.imgur.com/HcLsBtY.png)

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the -Werror flag was set in Build Settings, Other Warning Flags. I just removed -Werror.

Answer (score 2):

In my case this error was caused by a sub-project within the main project having "Treat warnings as errors" set to YES.

To fix:

- Go to **build settings** for your main project or sub-project (search for .xcodeproj to find all subprojects)
- type in **warnings** into search box
- Set "treat warnings as errors" to **NO**

[image]

This fixed my issue for xCode 5.1