# zxingwidget build error on ios 7.1

Tags: ios, iphone, zxing, ios7.1

I try to build my app, with xzingwidget, on xcode 5.1 and I get the following error.

'**CHECKSUM_EXCEPTION_H**' is used a header guard here, followed by #define of a different macro

I have to change some build setting?

**SOLUTION**

This [Xcode 5.1 unused consts treated as error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22322940/xcode-5-1-unused-consts-treated-as-error)
helped me to find the solution.

I removed all "Apple  LLVM 5.1 Custom Compiler Flags" in the ZXingWidget target, now everything works

Comment: What is xzingwidget? Is that the only error? Did you follow some sort of tutorials for this?

Comment: I use this:
http://basheerad.blogspot.it/2012/04/integrating-zxing-qr-code-reader-in.html
and this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968369/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7-when-using-zxing-library-in-xcode-4-5

With xcode 5.0.2 I can build my app, but with the new xcode 5.1 I get the error during the building phase

Comment: I really need more info. That can't be the only error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On deployment target iOS7 there seems to be the need to set the compilers to C++ 11 (sdt) as well as libc++ (LLVM)

After switching those settings the build runs successfully

You can refer to [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/zxing/V51KuppDEqg) for more info.

Comment: And how would one set the compilers to that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the lib.
It should be :

```
#ifndef __CHECKSUM_EXCEPTION_H__
#define __CHECKSUM_EXCEPTION_H__
....
```

instead of :

```
#ifndef __CHECKSUM_EXCEPTION_H__
#define __NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION_H__
....
```